# Web content is not loading in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have one iframe in my page that will load the local html content but not loading remote web content.

Here is the code :

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="http://localhost/test.html" width="520px" height="400px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

This is working.

But the following code is not working :

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="http://www.google.co.in/" width="520px" height="400px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Please any help

Comment: The second one needs to an internet connection to work.

Comment: Yes internet connecction is there,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses an X-FRAME-OPTIONS HTTP header to disallow putting their pages in iframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Almost all modern browsers will refuse to put pages with this HTTP header in an iframe. There's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the console you see this:

```
[Error] Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame
because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

What means that Google doesn't want to be displayed in an iframe.

More about [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)